# Grant texthelp to a certain view for a person in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with Microsoft SQL server. I would like to grant permission to a certain person to a certain view. And with that information, I would like to give him access to sp_helptext to that view. Is that possible to grant certain view and sp_helptext to a person?

I have tried "grant execute on sp_helptext to UserName" but I don't want to give full access. I want to grant sp_helptext on certain views.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: I am working on Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON OBJECT :: <View_name> TO <userName>;
```

This only works on later versions of SQL Server, but I am not sure when it was introduced. (I think it works in 2005, but it was definitely available by 2008r2).

Comment: By your syntax, I can grant on views but I also want to grant sp_helptext to those specific views. Can you please kindly help me with that?

Comment: @HtutKhine I am unable to test it myself right now, but this should allow `sp_HelpText` to work for that user on the view. If it does not, then there is no way to do it so specifically, as it is not possible to secure or grant rights on a *set of parameters* to a procedure. It's either this or granting more general access.

Comment: Hi @RBarry, Thank you very much. The code you give best fits my situation and it works.